# Number of Rs in a string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

I have an assignment where I'm given a string S containing the letters 'R' and 'K', for example "RRRRKKKKRK".

I need to obtain the maximum number of 'R's that string could possibly hold by flipping characters i through j to their opposite. So:

```
for(int x = i; x < j; x++)
{
  if S[x] = 'R'
  {
    S[X] = 'S';
  }
  else
  {
    S[X] = 'R';
  }
}
```

However, I can only make the above call **once**.

So for the above example: "RRRRKKKKRK".

You would have i = 4 and j = 8 which would result in: "RRRRRRRRKR" and you would then output the number of R's in the resulting string: 9.

My code partially works, but there are some cases that it doesn't. Can anyone figure out what is missing?

#### Sample Input

```
2
RKKRK
RKKR
```

#### Sample Output

```
4
4
```

#### My Solution

My solution which works only for the first case, I don't know what I'm missing to complete the algorithm:

```
int max_R = INT_MIN;
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < s.size(); j++)
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        string t = s;

        if (t[j] == 'R')
        {
            t[j] = 'K';
        }
        else
        {
            t[j] = 'R';
        }

        for (int b = 0; b < s.size(); b++)
        {
            if (t[b] == 'R')
            {
                cnt++;

                if (cnt  > max_R)
                {
                    max_R = cnt;
                }
            }

        }
    }

}


cout << max_R << endl;
```

Comment: Is there a question anywhere in here?

Comment: @BillLynch Yeah...but it is homework. He wants us to solve the above problem. He's got it working for the sample, but more details need to be provided so we understand what he is expecting and what he is getting. I'll work on cleaning up.

Comment: its not a home work, I'm practicing problem solving and enhancing my skills. I couldn't solve it with other test cases, the algorithm needs to be refined

Comment: I didn't say it was a bad question (I'd flag it if it was). It just is written as a homework question. It actually is a packing algorithm.

Comment: @SailorCire but what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: You're flipping right away instead of counting. Count the number of K's and count the number of R's. If the number of K's flipped outweighs R's flipped then do it. Otherwise keep going. I have a *very* sloppy answer written up, but if I post it it'll get downvoted to oblivion, because it isn't complete. So your solution flips all letters so RKKKRRRRR would do worse that the original string.

Comment: but how did you know about the count issue ? it's not mentioned at all in the problem. The problem looks like it's straight forward flipping K's by R and vice versa.

Comment: Come on, guys, this has nothing to do with the knapsack. Knapsack is NP-complete, and this problem has a brain-dead n^3 solution.

Comment: First, you have to transform your string in vector of int which count the number of consecutive R/K (positive for R, negative for K) (so `"RRRRKKKKRK"` becomes `{4, -3, 1, -1}` ) then you still have to find the algorithm to know which range to reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to carefully think about your solution. Do you understand, what it does?

First, let’s forget that the input file may contain multiple tests, so let’s get rid of the `while` loop. Now, we have just two `for` loops. The second one obviously just counts `R`’s in the processed string. But what does the first one do?

The answer is that the first loop flips all the letters from the second one (i.e. which has index `1`) till the end of the string. We can see that in the first testcase:

```
RKKRK
```

it is indeed the optimal solution. The string turns into `RRRKR` and we get four `R`’s. But in the second case:

```
RKKR
```

the string turns into `RRRK` and we get *three* `R`’s. While if we flipped just the letters from 2 to 3 (i.e. indices `1` to `2`) we could get `RRRR` which has *four* `R`’s.

So your algorithm always flips letters from index `1` to the end, but this is not always optimal. What can we do? How do we know which letters to flip? Well, there are some smart solutions, but the easiest is to just try all possible combinations!

You can flip all the letters from `0` to `1`, count the number of `R`’s, remember it. Get back to the original string, flip letters from `0` to `2`, count `R`’s, remember it and so on till you flip from `0` to `n-1`. Then you flip letters from `1` to `2`, from `1` to `3`, etc. And the answer is the largest value you remembered.

This is horribly inefficient, but this works. After you get more practice in solving algorithmic problems, get back to this task and try to figure out more efficient solutions. (Hint: if you consider building the optimal answer incrementally, that is by going through the string char by char and transforming the optimal solution for the substring `s[0..i]` into the optimal solution for `s[0..i+1]` you can arrive to a pretty straightforward O(n^2) algorithm. This can be enhanced to O(n), but this step is slightly more involved.)

---

Here is the sketch of this solution:

```
def solve(s):
  answer = 0
  for i in 0..(n-1)
    for j in i..(n-1)
      t = copy(s)  # we will need the original string later
      flip(t, i, j)  # flip letters from i to j in t
      c = count_R(t)  # count R's in t
      answer = max(answer, c)
  return answer
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the O(N^3) solution is three nested loop correct ? can you show pseudo code ?

Comment: can you check my modified algorithm ?

Comment: @andre I added pseudocode to my answer. Note that there are two loops (which is n^2) and we also need to flip letters (which brings us to n^3). Again, this is completely brain-dead as, e.g. you don’t need to _actually_ flip letters to count `R`’s, you can just count `R`’s from `0` to `i-1`, then count `K`’s from `i` to `j` and again count `R`’s from `j+1` to `n-1`.

Comment: @andre Checked your modified code. You are still not trying all the possible values for the _right_ bound, as a result you are still getting wrong answer on the second test.

Comment: @andre I don’t think anything actually changed. You are still always flipping _all_ the letters up to the end of the string. Just take a pen and paper and execute your algorithm yourself on the second testcase, you’ll see that you never consider the possibility of flipping just the two `R`’s in the middle.

Comment: I'm just struggling on applying  flipp (i,j), would you fix my c code please ? I need to learn. i'm just exercising problem solving

Comment: what's inside your function flip(i,j) ? another for loop from i to j ?

Comment: @andre Yes, the `flip` function is basically your second loop but not from `i` to `n-1` (as you have it now), but, as you said, from `i` to `j`. So, you should have two loops (those that you see in my pseudocode) and the third one hidden in `flip`; you already have the first one, but you are missing the second one. And the `flip` is your second loop run through `i` to `j`.

Comment: @andre My pseudocode can be translated to C in a pretty straightforward way. You just have to implement the `flip` (as you correctly said, that’s a `for` loop from `i` to `j`) and `count` (a loop from `0` to `n-1`) functions. I also suggest you actually structure your code as in my pseudocode, that is, _actually have_ the `flip` and `count` functions. That way it will be easier for you to reason about your code (and test/debug it).

Answer (score 3):

How about turning this into the [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) which has O(n) solution?

Run through the string once, giving 'K' a value of 1, and 'R' a value of -1.

E.g For `'RKRRKKKKRKK'` you produce an array -> `[-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]` -> `[-1, 1, -2, 4, -1, 2]` (I grouped consecutive -1s and 1s to be more clear)

Apply Kadane's algorithm on the generated array. What you get from doing this is the maximum number of 'R's you can obtain from flipping 'K's.

Continuing with the example, you find that the maximum subarray is `[4, -1, 2]` with a sum of 5.

Now add the absolute value of the negative values outside this subarray with the sum of your maximum subarray to obtain your answer.

In our case, only -1 and -2 are negative and outside the subarray. We get |-1| + |-2| + 5 = 8

Comment: @kirelagin a corner case could handle that

Comment: How did you come up with that solution ? I want to learn !! that's very trickey and it really answers the question in a fast way

Comment: I don't see how you are getting `13+11` and how you got 34 as the correct solution? Sorry if I was unclear about the last step, I edited my answer. The last step is just adding the number of 'R's outside the range you are flipping to the number of 'R's you will obtain from flipping.

Comment: @Jarod I assigned 'K's the value of 1 and 'R's the value of -1! So, maximum sub array is {5, -1, 8} with a sum of 12. Then add the absolute value of the negative values outside this subarray with this sum: |-10| + |-6| + 12 = 28. Not sure why you were flipping the -10 which represents 10 'R's (We are maximizing 'R's, not 'K's)

Comment: @j449li: sorry, miss read your solution, you use Maximum sub-array to find the array to reverse.